# Can't get focus on editText when children are added in layout

Tags: java, android

i am adding a spinner, an image and an editText in a linearLayout everytime i click a button.

Now whenever i add this layout , editText shows blinking, means it has focus but the keyboard won't show up. Even i click on it, the keyboard won't show up. What most i can do is to click somewhere else and then back at the editText to make it show keyboard and proper focus.

I am using following code, how can i fix this bug.

```
 viewHolder.title = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.AddNewDetail);

  view.setTag(viewHolder);  
 layout.addView(view);
```

Comment: try using `android:focusable="true"  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should force the softkeyboard show.

```
((InputMethodManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
            .showSoftInput(editText,
                    InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

and close it

```
((InputMethodManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
            .hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(),
                    0);
```

and focus on edittext

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

May you have added the below line in for your activity in manifeast file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

try removing it or you can manaually use the requestfocus method to get focus. try the below method.

```
edittext.requestFocus();
```